# Using System.Net.Http.HttpClient within a .aspx page (website)

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am updating a .Net Webforms website (not application; running .Net 4.6.2).  The site consists of .aspx pages.

I need to make several requests to a number of DIFFERENT third party resources from one of the web pages.  All of the Microsoft documentation states:

> System.Net.Http.HttpClient should be used instead

However, all examples given in the documentation show **console applications** making use of System.Net.Http.HttpClient, as all the methods of HttpClient are Asynchronous and I suspect would be rather difficult to use the required methods within a .aspx web page (or not?)

I am trying to find any examples whereby System.Net.Http.HttpClient is used within a .aspx page?

Is (or should) System.Net.Http.HttpClient be used with .aspx web pages?

Any advice on the best way to make MULTIPLE HTTP requests from within a .aspx web page would be appreciated.

Please note that I am NOT looking for third-party libraries that I would need to install and add to the project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use WebRequest, even though Microsoft doesn't recommend that.

[WebRequest Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sb.ToString());
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = getResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

It works fine for me and does what I need it to do.

Hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes - that is what I thought - stick to the tried and true / tested -- works just fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Never change a running system. :-)